# How put an argument inside quotation marks?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I made a public sub and wanted to put the argument into an SQL command:

```
"select * from '" & argument & "'"
```

but always get a syntax error.

I've tried changing the `&` to `+` and using a `string var` instead of an argument

`conn` is an `oledbconnection`

```
Public Sub panggildata(datagrid As Object, table As String)
    konek()
    DA = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM '" & table & "'", conn)
    DS = New DataSet
    DS.Clear()
    DA.Fill(DS, "'" & table & "'")
    datagrid.DataSource = DS.Tables("'" & table & "'")
    datagrid.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I want to display the table in the datagrid.

Comment: Why do you want to have the table name within single quotes?

Comment: Is it a syntax error in the VB or the SQL?  If it's the SQL then changing the VB code is pointless.  Also, it's almost guaranteed that what you're trying to do is wrong, so finding the right way to do it is impossible.  What is the value of `table` when it fails and what type of database is it?

Comment: Also, what's the point of creating a `DataSet` when you just intend to use one `DataTable`?  Just create a `DataTable` and use that.

Comment: You didn't tell the SQL dialect but putting a table name in single quotes is at least unclean in all of them and erroneous in most of them if not all.

Comment: To answer your question; to include the double quote character in a string, double the quotes. `Dim s = """cat"""` This tiny example shows 3 triple quote characters on each side of cat. The other comments and answer in this case, shows you that this is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On line 3, you don't need to add a single-quotes when specifying a table in a sql, so instead use this code

   `DA = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & table, conn)`
2. Also don't need to put a single-quotes on each table argument

   `DA.Fill(DS, table)`

   `datagrid.DataSource = DS.Tables(table)`